# java how to make asynchronous task run only when other threads not active

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a fixed thread pool for scheduled job, now I just have only one scheduled job:

```
App.setSes(Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1));
App.getSes().scheduleAtFixedRate(new SPCPollingTask(), 0, Integer.parseInt(SPCService.INSTANCE.getConfig("scheduleInterval")), TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

And another thread pool for asynchronous task:

```
App.setAes(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, new ThreadFactory(){
            @Override
            public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                Thread thread = new Thread(r);
                thread.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
                return thread;
            }

        }));
```

In the `SPCPollingTask`, I submit asynchronous task to it like this:

```
if(total > 50){
            int i = 51;
            long c = System.currentTimeMillis();
            do{
                App.getAes().submit(new Async1225Task(bdhm, ccxh, accountNo, subAccountNo, beginDate, endDate, i));
                i = i + 50;
            }while(i <= total);
            long n = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ARE.getLog().debug("[perf-hint]--submit task to AES takes " + StringUtil.formatLong((n-c), "#") + " ms");
        }
```

By doing this, I expect the scheduled task `SPCPollingTask` will always finish very quickly, but on my windows PC, it done at almost the end of the whole asynchronous task. I uploaded my code to a linux server and got better result but still not good enough.

How can I make sure my scheduled `SPCPollingTask` will always do it's job first, then asynchronous tasks can do their job?

I am running these on Tomcat 6 with JDK6.

Comment: Do you submit more than 1 async tasks in your scheduled task?

Comment: @Xipo yes, 80 async tasks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way right now that would require the least tampering of your code is to add all the async tasks that generated in your scheduled job in a list, and then submit them all at the end of your scheduled jobs execution.

This is easily done:

1. At the beginning of your `run()` method of `SPCPollingTask` just add

   ```
   List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<Task>(80);
   ```
2. Replace all `App.getAes().submit('any task goes here');` with

   ```
   tasks.add('any task goes here');
   ```
3. At the end of the run method

   ```
   App.getAes().invokeAll(tasks);
   ```

Bare in mind that `invokeAll` is ''blocking'', and so you should consider submitting all tasks in the list using a loop